# Showing Error on using require('express')

Tags: node.js, express

I Have installed Express framework globally. 
When I am using it in app. it is showing error of not finding the module.

Comment: Although i used npm link express in current directory to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicate that you didnt installed correctly the Express, I recommend to you install the Express locally on your project.
Use this command:

```
//init your app
npm init
//install the express on your project
npm install express --save
```

See ya!